# Trying to get DeepSpeech to work. SoX not found even though I pip installed it?

Tags: python, mozilla-deepspeech

The error I'm getting is:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] SoX not found, use 16000hz files or
> install it: The system cannot find the file specified

My audio file is from an mp4 video file that was then converted to a WAV file from VLC. The sampling rate is 8000 Hz by default, and it appears that DeepSpeech needs 16kHz files and therefore the SoX plugin.

I ran pip install SoX and `pip install --upgrade SoX`.
Requirement already satisfied: SoX in `e:\downloads\deep speech\lib\site-packages (1.4.1)`
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in e:\downloads\deep speech\lib\site-packages (from SoX) (1.21.4)
So it's here. I then added E:\Downloads\Deep Speech\Lib\site-packages to system environment variables on Windows just in case. I'm new to Python in general and stumped here.

Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: Sox isn't a Python package. You'll need to have the program itself installed.

Comment: Okay, great. I've got it working now. I don't know if I should make another post (because it's a different issue), but the transcription is really awful at the moment. Is that the current state of DeepSpeech or can I use a better model for training? I currently run 'deepspeech --model deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm --scorer deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer --audio Test.wav > output.txt'

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue, Fix it by converting the audio rate to 16000hz.
Please try

```
`ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 16000 output.wav`
```

Comment: Worked in 2023!

Answer (score 3):

You should install sox from `apt-get` ubuntu, not from `pip`.

```
sudo apt-get install sox
```